# What do I do if somebody asks me to join his accusation of my colleague of academic misconduct?

Tags: publications, ethics

One of my colleagues at my institution, Prof. A, is the editor of a journal, Journal X, (and I am not involved in the journal in any way). I received an email by a professor, Prof. B, who had submitted two articles to Journal X and accuses Prof. A. of intentionally delaying the publication of these articles by not handling them properly. Prof. B claims that Prof. A did not answer his queries per email and that another editor of Journal X also did not answer his emails. The email I got from Prof. B was openly targeted to several other colleagues at my institution and also to a number of other people I do not know and also to Prof A. At the end of his email, Prof. B asks me (and the others - more or less verbatim) "Is this attitude of Prof. A normal or are there any unethical elements [...]?" and to "join in this story".

I found it disturbing that Prof. B wrote such an email to such an audience and I would say that his way of addressing the situation was not ok. However, I wonder what my reaction should be. Normally, I would just stop by at Prof. A's office, but I am on sabbatical leave so this is not an option. I do not know more details about the issue of the publication, but I think that these do not really matter in this case, as I only want to ask about what I should do:

- Should I answer Prof. B that this way of addressing the issue was not ok?
- Should I inform Prof. A that I found this email inappropriate?
- Should I just act as if I haven't read this email?

I would especially appreciate answers from people with experience on an editorial board, but other guiding comments are also helpful.

Comment: I don't think anyone can give you a canonical answer. For that reason, sadly, I would vote to close this as being opinion based.

Comment: If this went all around your department, and included both prof A and prof B, have you tried talking to your department chair about it?  Regardless, it sounds like a situation to avoid.

Comment: I don't think there's a right answer, it's like game of thrones in academia.

Comment: Because there isn't any ethical imperative here, I think the answers depend too much on your relationships to the people involve, your position at the institution, etc. Your question might provoke some interesting discussion but I think any answers will be based on opinion and therefore your question isn't really appropriate here. You might be able to rephrase/restate the question to get around these issues.

Comment: Without further facts, you can not form an opinion, it's as simple as that. If the facts support such an accusation, the first point of contact is the publisher, then possibly the institution of Prof. A's dean. If you are not the dean, you have nothing further to say until you are asked by them (I assume you do not report to Prof. B). This has crossed the line of informal inquiry.

Comment: I agree with most comments. If you don't feel the same way for Prof A, I would disregard the email completely. If you are close with Prof A, you can talk to him about it. If you feel more supportive for Prof B for other reasons, then you could contact him, but I don't think you feel this way and I wouldn't either. Politics in Academia are as common as everywhere else.

Comment: 2 People at odds, you don't know who's right, should you take a side? Never!

Comment: I don't think Prof. B was specifically asking you to join the accusation. As I read it, he's probably looking for other evidence of Prof. A wrongdoings by surveying a large number of colleagues.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments and answers. I decided to let Prof A know that I found the email inappropriate and do not plan to do anything further just in case he worries if this campaign gains traction or not. Also I ticked Dan Romiks answer since it is the most well founded one.

Comment: Yet again, I find Mark Burgess's article [Why I stopped caring about peer review, and learned to love the work](http://markburgess.org/blog_peer.html) to be extremely relevant.  *"To say it like it is, there is essential bribery and corruption at the heart of the peer review process, as there is in any realm of human power. The result is not always a quality assurance."*

Comment: @Wildcard I think you jumped to some conclusion too quick. I do not see any evidence for bribery or corruption yet; I apply Hanlon's razor with "stupidity" replaced by "mishap".

Comment: @Dirk, I didn't mean to infer either Prof A or B is involved in bribery or corruption.  I suggest reading the article I linked; it's quite short.  My conclusion is that the concept of "peer review" is fundamentally broken as a means of advancing scientific knowledge, not that those who engage in the peer review process are each individually unethical.  (Note that Mark Burgess was a full tenured Professor before he left Academia.)

Comment: @Wildcard (or Mark Burgess if that's your real name ;-)), I read the article you linked to. Your and Mark Burgess's opinions about peer review may or may not be interesting and may or may not have any merit to them, but in any case as far as I can tell they have nothing whatsoever to do with the question being discussed. OP asked how to deal with a workplace situation involving a couple of colleagues, not for an analysis of the peer review process, which is completely tangential to the story.

Comment: @DanRomik, hence why I posted the link in a comment rather than expanding upon it and making it an answer.  ;)  In IT we refer to "addressing the root cause" and I think it should at least be considered/mentioned that the peer review process *itself* may have contributed to this problem.  (Aside: I'm not Mark, but I learned CFEngine from someone who learned it directly from him.)

Comment: One of the best pieces of advice I got in school was - Don't fight other people's fight, you fight your fights. If it doesn't involve you, don't get involve. If it does, only get involved to the point that it is needed.

Comment: Are we sure it's not Professor X......?   But yeah, just tell the guy to leave you out of it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Should I answer Prof. B that this way to address the issue was not ok?

You *can*, if you feel strongly about it. But I think it is perfectly okay not to respond. First of all, you are one of a long list of recipients, so it would be quite unreasonable for Prof. B to expect each and every recipient of the email to set aside their work and life to dedicate themselves to studying in detail the situation he is describing and then write an equally detailed reply. Basically, to put it bluntly, Prof. B's email can be reasonably classified as spam and there is certainly no obligation to reply to it in any way.

Second of all, you are on sabbatical, which is a sacred time you should devote to nurturing your own interests and passions and ignoring the daily trivia and tedium of academic life. The case for not responding is therefore even stronger (to the extent it needed any strengthening).

> Should I inform Prof. A that I found this email inappropriate?

Again, you have been implicated in this business completely through the actions of others and have no duty to take any action. If you feel strongly enough about the inappropriate email that you feel compelled to write to Prof. A, go ahead. But there is absolutely no need to do so.

> Should I just do as if I haven't read this email?

I wouldn't falsely pretend that I haven't read the email, if that's what you mean - that would be dishonest and unprofessional (and besides, you have now documented publicly your knowledge of the email ;-)). Nor would I plan on saying (as Wolfgang Bangerth suggests in his answer) that I deleted it since it was "none of my business" (I don't think that unethical behavior by others is none of my business - it would be perfectly appropriate to consider it my business if I were so inclined). But as I said it would be completely appropriate to file the email away (or delete it, as you prefer) and take no further action. Whether you *should* do that depends on whether you are interested in getting involved in the story.

Comment: What if Prof. B is a senior, established colleague, Prof. A is a junior, insecure colleague and the OP is senior and established? In that case, I think there might be an ethical obligation to make sure somebody is taking care of it. (Possibly by emailing the department chair or somebody else in a suitable position and not on sabbatical.)

Comment: @cfr yes you have a point here - as I said in the answer, I don't subscribe to the worldview presented in Wolfgang Bangerth's answer according to which ethical transgressions by person B against person A are "none of my business" if I am not person A or B, so certainly there is a moral case for intervening in egregious enough situation. On the other hand, saying that there is a moral _duty_ to intervene is a much stronger statement that I would reserve for truly extreme situations that form a much more smaller subset of scenarios than the relatively generic situation you are describing. ...

Comment: I admit it is a bit generic and would depend on the details. I really meant that the OP's case could be filled out in ways which would create a moral obligation, I think, and not that the details I added are themselves sufficient for that.

Comment: ... As a general rule, it seems a bit of a stretch to argue that a senior person who is secure in their life/career has an ethical obligation to put their life and work on hold and combat every injustice against a less powerful person that they ever come across. After all, at any given moment I am in fact aware of many societal injustices of this sort. If I were required to fight all of them, I would never get anything else done. So overall I disagree with your claim about an ethical obligation for intervention, as I said except in truly extreme and egregious circumstances.

Comment: A junior colleague is hardly somebody you just come across. And I am hardly suggesting putting everything else on hold. Indeed, since the OP is on sabbatical, I suggested ensuring somebody is taking care of it rather than getting involved directly. I think senior academics do, for example, have defeasible obligations to protest bullying in their own departments.

Comment: @cfr good points. I still disagree, but it is a weak disagreement and pertains mainly to the level of generality at which your argument would apply - overall your view is quite reasonable.

Answer (score 31):

Delete the email (or move it to one of your folders where you keep old ones).

From what you describe, you have no business joining the complaint since you *have* no complaint again colleague A. It is, in other words, not something that actually affects you: someone has beef with colleague A, and that is their business, nor yours. Worse, if you did get involved -- even if just by writing back to B --, there is nothing for you to gain, just collegiality to lose. It's neither worth your time nor your reputation to act any further than reading, then ignoring the email.

If anyone ever asks you whether you got the email, just tersely say "Yes, I got it; it was none of my business, so I ignored it."

Comment: I would advise against telling the person to delete the email. In sensitive cases like this, it is always wise to retain a paper trail; even if you didn't respond to the email directly.

Comment: @DIMMSum But the matter of fact is this *isn't* a sensitive case for the OP. Somebody is angry at somebody else, and none of that has anything to do with the OP. Nobody can expect the OP to keep a paper trail about an issue that has literal zero to do with him. Seriously, this sounds more like one of these crank mails that we academics are prone to occasionally get. The usual reaction is to delete it and get on with one's life.

Comment: @xLeitix Or archive it and get on with one's life? I don't see the point in deleting something like this if it takes the exact same amount of effort to just store it out of site.

Comment: That's my approach -- I just archive everything just in case I may ever need to get to it again. I never do, but who knows. My point was not to advocate deleting it from your archive, but to just delete it from the list of things you're concerned about. How you do that I'm happy to leave to the OP. (My personal opinion is that of @xLeitix -- it's none of your concern, nor can anyone expect it to be, so you may as well delete it if you wanted to.)

Answer (score 3):

If you have knowledge, independently of B's accusation, that A is behaving badly, it's up to you to join B or not, depending on how much you care. If you don't have any such knowledge then you shouldn't.

If you have knowledge that B's accusations are wrong then you should inform B if you think B is mistaken, and you should inform A if you think B is intentionally spreading false accusations. If you have no knowledge that B's accusations are wrong then you may contact A about it or not, depending on how much you care.

Consider that getting involved in any way may cause you inconvenience, and not getting involved when someone is wronged may cause you a bad conscience (or worse).

Answer (score 1):

This sort of complaints shall be solved with

1. prof. A himself;
2. prof. A's superiors (dean,...)

If you are not entitled to command prof. A this e-mail is probably a campaign to dishonest prof. A. Of course, prof. B might be that desperate, but it think it is implausible scenario.

I would forward the e-mail as it is to prof. A with full list of recipients with comment:

> Dear prof. A
>   I have recieved following e-mail recently and I think you should be informed about the campaign against you.

Or you can mark it as SPAM and forget about it.

Comment: If I read the OP correctly, Prof. A has already received the e-mail along with other people.

Comment: @svavil Oh, I missed that note. Then the first and last sentences are my answer.